# SSLLabs' SSLTest vs. nmap ssl-enum-ciphers

Tags: tls, nmap, vulnerability-scanners, ciphers

Recently I conducted a [SSL server test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to assess the SSL configuration of my server. While the overall grade A+ was pretty good, it was found that the server supports several cipher suites that are considered weak according to SSLLabs (actually only 2 out of 8 were ok).

[image: SSL Cipher Assessment]

These ciphers are reported to be weak according to [cipersuite.info](https://ciphersuite.info/cs/) as well.

Now I contacted my hosting support and asked them to provide a stronger configuration option but they claimed that the mentioned ciphers are strong (A rating) and referred to the `ssl-enum-ciphers` nmap script and the corresponding rating:

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|_  least strength: A
```

I had a look at the script and it looks like mainly the hashing algorithm (not MD1/4/5 and not SHA1) and the key length are taken into consideration when it comes to the rating. Issues with ciphers using CBC or RSA don't seem to be reflected at all.

Is it ok to use the `ssl-enum-ciphers` script as reference regarding rating of TLS ciphers? My hitherto reference always used to be SSLLabs and the corresponding Qualys scan.

Is there anything more convincing than the SSLLabs' rating to make my hosting support rethink their assessment?

Comment: It is more complex than just looking at the cipher. There are attacks on CBC ciphers (therefore weak) but there are also mitigations (which might result in not weak) - which might or might not be implemented. See [NIST SP 800-52 Guidelines for TLS Implementations](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-52r2.pdf) - regarding CBC specifically section 3.3.2 Implementation Guidelines. And weak also does not mean actually exploitable in common scenarios. And choice of ciphers also depends on the kind of clients which need to be supported.

Comment: Also check out https://testssl.sh/